# Does VS Code have an equivalent feature to Notepad++'s "Project Panels" feature?

Tags: visual-studio-code, notepad++

In Notepad++ there is a feature called "Project Panels" (https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/session/#project-panels) that lets you create so called "Projects", which are basically a tree-view with files (even from different directories) and directories of your choice. Is there an equivalent of that in VS Code?

Comment: Not in a native-builtin way AFAIK but there might be an extension

Comment: To people voting to close this as "not about programming or software development", see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337021/11107541.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=herdingbits.file-focus . This extension does exactly the same as the "Projects panel" feature and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to this that I'm aware of existing in VS Code without any extensions is [Multi-Root Workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces), which allows you to map arbitrary folder workspaces to what are like virtual subdirectories of a virtual folder, and customize workspace settings per root. But you can only "mount" these virtual subdirectories to the root virtual folder. I don't know much about the Project Panels feature of Notepad++, but it sounds to be much more of a lightweight feature than Multi-Root Workspaces and that they're designed for different purposes.

There is a feature request issue ticket on the VS Code Github repo for something that would make it more like what you are describing though: [Hirerarchical multi-root layout #76904](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76904). <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup> Also possibly interesting to you: [Support "perspectives" like approach in VSCode #95182](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95182).

Comment: Yeah, basically the cool thing about the projects panel is that you create "conceptual" folders maybe with most used files or some files of the same type but coming from completely different directories. It is so strange and annoying not having the same on vscode, more so if you are switching and were accustomed in working that way.

Comment: well, you can always look for an extension on the visual studio marketplace that does this. Or if you don't find one and have time to spare and an appetite to learn some things, write one yourself. This is as far as my answer goes though- at least for now.